# Регулирование частоты CPU в линукс

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, manjaro

Имеется manjaro kde на ядре 6.1.23 на ноутбуке с процессором ryzen 6800h (Redmibook 2022). В чем заключается проблема:
С помощью утилиты `cpupower` на ядре 6.0 я могу устанавливать любую частоту процессора, что помогает сэкономить заряд (проверял с помощью `powertop`).
На ядре 6.1, минимальная частота, что я могу выставить, это 1.6Ггц, и переключается она шагами: 1.6, 1.8, 3.2. Когда на предыдущем ядре я могу выставить любую частоту в пределе от 0,4Ггц до 4,8Ггц.

Вывод `sudo cpupower frequency-info`:

```
analyzing CPU 11:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 11
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 11
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.60 GHz - 4.78 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.20 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 3.20 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.60 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  3200MHz
    Pstate-P1:  1800MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1600MHz
```

На ядре 6.0 вывод аналогичен, только 6-я строка с пределами выглядит по другому:

```
hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.78 GHz
```

С чем это связано и как починить? Часто приходится работать без питания и время работы от аккумулятора очень важно. Тем более, что частоты 1Ггц на 16 потоках хватает, чтоб без фризов работать в офисном пакете и на фоне смотреть ютуб.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Я думаю, это связано с внутренним устройством кластеров ядер на чипе (и не чинится). Вообще, для экономии можете попробовать  отключать лишние ядра (кроме нулевого), записав 0 в /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<N>/online (скорее всего это будет действовать сразу на 2 ядра (из 16), поскольку похоже, что "настоящих" ядер там 8 (а 16 это если считать hyperthreding))

Comment: @avp, но ведь на ядре 6.0 регулирование частоты работает, и оно действительно применяется не ступенчато. Значит, дело именно в системе, а не железе. Раз меняется только ядро, значит, скорее всего, дело именно в нём.
Хотелось бы разобраться, ибо по некоторым причинам на ядро 6.0 не хочется возвращаться.
Возможно, нужно пересобрать ядро с другими параметрами. Опыт имеется, но в этом случае даже не знаю, что изменять

Comment: @avp, при записи в /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<N>/online нуля, пропадает один поток, а не два. Видимо это именно на них работает, а не на физические ядра

Comment: а пакет `amd-ucode` стоит? может в этом дело...

Comment: посмотрите какой там драйвер используется `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver` -- **acpi-cpufreq** или **amd_pstate**. По идее для AMD Ryzen 6000+ серии лучше использоваться **amd_pstate**, но вроде как **acpi-cpufreq** идёт по умолчанию, поэтому **acpi-cpufreq** нужно добавить в черный список, а модуль **amd_pstate** указать явно, возможно нужно будет установить его в режим `passive` - [amd-pstate.html#passive-mode](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/pm/amd-pstate.html#passive-mode). **PS** сразу не заметил у вас `driver: acpi-cpufreq`, пробуйте тогда **amd_pstate**

Comment: @PavelGridin, да, стоит. По идее, все пакеты и настройки системы должны быть идентичны, раз только с другого ядра загружаюсь.

Comment: @Zt. Действительно, на ядре 6.0 драйвер amd-pstate, а на 6.1 acpi-cpufreq. Выглядит как потенциальное решение проблемы. На работе попробую разобраться, как перенастроить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогло добавление аргументов в файл `/etc/default/grub`, в строку `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="<старые параметры> amd_pstate.enable=1 amd_pstate.shared_mem=1 amd_pstate=passive initcall_blacklist=acpi_cpufreq_ini"
```

Затем

```
sudo update-grub
```

Большое спасибо всем за помощь.